# JQuery + ASP.NET доступ к элементу Label

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-webforms, веб-программирование

Моя задача в следующем: прочитать после загрузки страницы значение метки с именем "lbl_login0". Через `GetElementByID` все работает, проблем нет. У меня не получается то же сделать в JQuery:

Пишу код:

```
label = $("<%#lbl_login0.ClientID %>");
        alert(label);
```

Он не работает, смотрю исходник страниц в браузере:

```
label = $("");
        alert(label );
```

Выполняется код у меня в разделе `$(document).ready(function () {...`

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ситуацию**

**Обновление**

Я нашел такой вариант: `$("[id$=lbl_login0]")`, и он сработал. Есть еще варианты? Хочется знать, почему мой вариант в вопросе не заработал.

Answer (score 1):

Заработал этот вариант :

```
$("[id$=lbl_login0]")
```